# "Success" or "Complete" method for Ember Data collection retrieval

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my app I have a 1 to M relationship modeled like so:

```
Social.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    created: DS.attr("date"),
    text: DS.attr("string"),
    metrics: DS.hasMany("Social.Metric"),
});

Social.Metric = DS.Model.extend({
    label: DS.attr('string'),
    value: DS.attr('number'),
    message: DS.belongsTo('Social.Message'),
});
```

When Ember Data makes a call to retrieve messages, the data packet looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 13, 
        "created": "2013-05-20T21:35:56Z"
        "text": "You got to let the roots grow deep, and stop worrying about the leaves", 
        "metrics": [
            "reach-13", 
            "click-13"
        ]
    }
]
```

We're using sideloading to then retrieve the metrics, and the return data for that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        id: "reach-13",
        value: 3,
        label: "reached"
    },
    {
        id: "reply-13",
        value: 2,
        label: "reply"
    },
]
```

This process is working great, with no flaws. But because there might be a large number of messages, each of which has a collection of metrics, the time to display metrics can be 3 or more seconds. On each message I'd like to add a loading spinner in place of the metrics, then remove it once the metrics for that message have returned. I've got the spinner added, but can't figure out how to remove it once the collection of metrics has returned to the client.

**Does Ember have an event or method on the Controller that fires when an *entire collection* of data is returned to the client?**

I know that the [Model lifecycle has hooks like this](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/), but I don't care about the individual models, I'm looking for something higher up, for the entire set of metrics (for each message)

Here's a quick screencast of what's happening right now. 
http://screencast.com/t/CIx3Aikck3

Answer (score 0):

Each `Message` and `Metric` model instance has its own model lifecycle hooks. In addition, `DS.ManyArray`s, which implement `DS.hasMany` relationships, also have an `isLoaded` property (one for the entire array).

So the key is in your handlebars template. Wrap the metrics in the `isLoaded` condition, not the entire Message. In the context of a Message:

```
<div>{{created}}</div>
<div>{{text}}</div>
<div>
  {{#if metrics.isLoaded}}
    {{#each metric in metrics}}
      {{! Display metric here. }}
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    <img src='spinner.gif'>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

`ManyArray`s also have a `didLoad` event that gets triggered when `isLoaded` is set to true, but for what you're describing, you shouldn't need it.